# Does storing large sessions slow down response time and server

Tags: php, mysql, linux, facebook, session

I am in the process of creating a Facebook App for my website which includes functionality that requires the users friends list.

Retrieving the friends is no problem, what I am struggling to decide, is how to store them.

1. **Option 1 -** Store the users in my MySQL database, I have opted not to go for this as my database will become very heavy, very quickly. In addition, I will need to create a table for each individual Facebook user!
2. **Option 2 -** Store the Facebook friends array in a session which is updated every half an hour to ensure new friends are included. **Ignore the fact that the session updates every half an hour,** is it a bad idea to store, what can be a very large array, within a session?

The website is likely to be receiving high volumes of traffic, and will therefore be storing a lot of these sessions.

Although I am an experienced developer, I am not overly experienced with sessions in these circumstances. I would simply like to know whether or not this is a bad idea?

**Just to give you a little info on the typical friends array:**

1. Each array is multidimensional in the format {0[uid:1,name:Jo Bloggs,picture:test.jpg],1...}
2. A friends list typically ranges from 100 items to 5000 items, although averaging around 700. **These are not small!**

If this is a bad method for storing the friends, what other options (excluding MySQL) are there?

**Do sessions have an effect on memory (RAM) usage?**

Comment: `I will need to create a table for each individual Facebook user!` - you should not need to do this. If you think you do, your planned database schema is flawed.

Comment: Yes, sessions have an effect on the memory usage, since they are available to php when run/read. I would use session_save_handler to store sessions in a database. (And if really heavy data is stored to the session you could split the data in another table to keep "normal" session access and table small).

Comment: Go with a database, that's what it's for. And don't think the arrays won't get heavy. As for table for each person, not a problem. That's why they invented the create query. Also, you don't have to. Store them in a meny-to-meny fashion and you're all good.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. @DaveRandom, would you simply store the array in a longtext field? Or have a friends table with many many rows for each friend of each user? I cant see a way I could do it tidily without having a table for each user.

Comment: It depends how you need to access the data. If you need to query the database with (for example) "is this person friends with this person", then you would have a table of `friends` with a FK to the `users` table so you can do `SELECT * FROM friends WHERE user_id = '$userId'`, but if you just need to do "get all this persons friends" type queries, you could store all the data in 1 BLOB column as (eg) JSON. Before someone asks, I would use a BLOB because this is not subject to the 65536-character row length limit.

Comment: I will have to go for the latter option as the app requires me to have all of the friends at once. I had of course thought of this, but I felt that it was a little untidy to have a BLOB table column containing huge arrays. It seemed tidier to have separate tables for each user, excluding the fact that would mean a lot of tables. Thank you for your advice, much appreciated. Please can you post your response to the answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your requirements, I highly recommend installing MemCacheD on your server. See: http://memcached.org/ for more information.

Session is only for the current user logged in, so sharing the information would be hard between sessions. Also when the session goes away, so does the user data.

For memcached data is stored in key/value pairs.

So for a key, you could use facebook ID, and for the value, a serialized object of user data.

Comment: It seems that memcached is meant for 'small chunks of data'. The arrays I am storing are pretty large! Is this a problem?

Comment: I've got objects in the order of magnitude of megabytes.  However, you're just storing some of the information you get from the API so you don't have to waste calls for items you've already loaded once.  Say user1 has friends user2, user3, user4.  And user5 has friends user2, user6.  So when user5 comes into your app after user1, you won't have to query the API for user2's info, because you get a copy of it from cache. Correct? So you now can store just the friend's ID in each user object (instead of the fully inflated array of user objects for friends).

Comment: Its not as simple as that because you do not know whether X is friends with Y when they first sign on. In addition, memcached stores this data in RAM which could subsequently backfire as I am currently trying to reduce my RAM consumption on my server. What you have suggested is very helpful but I don't think it is actually relevant as it simply just speeds up queries as opposed to storing users friends in an efficient way.

Comment: You, my friend, have never used the power of memcached.  It's much more efficient than you think, unless you the coder abuses it. You the coder must build your objects to be efficient.  Memcached is tied to the data model you pass in.

Comment: I dont understand how you are suggesting me to store the friends array though. Should I be storing it in the database and then 'memcaching' the query result. Or can I simply store the array in memcached?

Comment: How large do you think I should set the cache? I currently only have 512MB RAM on my dedicated virtual

Comment: The friends array should only be an array of Int64 values.  Then you can use that Int64 user id to pull out the particular user information for that id.  64MB will be plenty.  You'd be suprised how small the JSON is for a user object (as long as you don't inflate each friend underneath)

Comment: Okay, will start installing it now. With reference to my other question, should I still be storing the friends in a database, or just the uid? Then store the friends in memcached, and update them each new session, or every after a period of time, whichever comes first.

Comment: I'd store them in memcached for 24 hours.  That way you've got fairly current information on the friend (how often would they change their bio or work history anyways?) and also you're not hammering the API to death (possibly causing facebook to shut down your app if abused).  Consider memcached to be your database unless you need to do table joins, etc, then I'd consider architecting in a permanent data store where joins would be useful.

Comment: All up and running smoothly, thank you!! Before I accept this as answered, could you possibly just answer a few more points I have? Firstly, are you positive that this will work fine, even if there are over 1000 people on my site at once, each with over 700 friends? Will my cache run out? Once I have stored an item in the cache, can I update it? Could you possibly give me a link to some good sample code so I can crack on and start learning my way around the API?

Comment: Yes, you can update items in memcached.  Memcached is smart and will roll out the oldest entry to make room for new entries and wont run out of memory.  I've got some C# examples, but not sure how they'd translate to PHP. Insert, Update, Remove are the three main calls you will make with memcached. It's very straight forward

Comment: Okay, assumed I would probably be able to. I think I am starting to understand what 'memcached' is. It sets up my server as a 'memcached' server, which effectively manages all of the storage. The PHP API simply communicates with the defined server. This is the impression I am getting from reading around. Am I correct? Is there any benefit in having more than one server? Excluding the obvious reason of shared memory. Dont worry about the examples, I am sure I will manage using the PHP site.

Comment: Yes, with more servers you have more memory to consume.  memcached does a good job of keeping up with multiple servers.  I'd suggest cutting this convo off as we've gone well offtopic of the original question.  While your questions are good, I think having them in their own question would be best for people also looking for similar information about memcached.

Comment: Yes I agree! Thank you very much for your help. I will likely post up a question in the next few hours with regards to memcache if I have any trouble. Thanks again